# Quick way to detect empty values via reflection in Go

Tags: reflection, go

I have a `int`/`string`/`bool`/etc.. value stored in an `interface{}` and want to determine if it's uninitialized, meaning that it has a value of either

- `0`
- `""`
- `false`
- or `nil`

How do I check this?

Comment: For more up to date and straightforward answers, see also [How to know if a variable of arbitrary type is Zero in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33115946)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Go 1.13](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.13#reflect) (Q3 2019) should simplify that detection process:

> The new [`Value.IsZero()`](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.IsZero) method reports whether a Value is the zero value for its type.

It is implemented in [`src/reflect/value.go`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/d9b13233378668a4fd24ac5d044e9d550cd2a8be/src/reflect/value.go#L1085-L1123), from [commit c40bffd](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/c40bffd90535bd9d5bf6a398f5227ff2c9aaed52) and [CL 171337](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/171337), resolving [issue 7501](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/7501)

See [playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/HZNA5Unj-FZ) (as soon as Go 1.13 is supported)

```golang
var p *string
v := reflect.ValueOf(p)

fmt.Printf("1.13 v.IsZero()='%v' vs. IsZero(v)='%v'\n", v.IsZero(), IsZero(v))

// Ouput:
// 1.13 v.IsZero()='true' vs. IsZero(v)='true'
```

However:

```golang
v = v.Elem()
fmt.Printf("1.13 v.Elem().IsZero()='%v' vs. IsZero(v.Elem())='%v'\n", v.IsZero(), IsZero(v))

// Panic:
//
// panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.IsZero on zero Value
```

As explained in [issue 46320](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/46320#issuecomment-965970859):

> The problem you are describing is due to the nature of interface types in Go, and to the fact that the reflect package is built on interface types.
>
> A value of interface type always describes some other value.
> When you pass a value of interface type to `reflect.ValueOf`, you get a reflection object describing that other value, not the value of interface type.
>
> To work with `interface` values with the `reflect` package you generally need to use pointers.
>
> This doesn't have anything to do with `IsZero()`, it's just how the `reflect` package works.
>
> ```golang
> package main
>
> import (
>   "fmt"
>   "reflect" 
> )
>
> func main() {
>   var c interface{}
>
>   fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(&c).Elem().Kind())
>   fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(&c).Elem().IsZero())
> }
> ```
>
> Basically, one needs to call [`IsValid()`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.IsValid) before [`IsZero()`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.IsZero)

Comment: playground example is not working

Comment: @SamirKape It is working, but the panic message, as reported in [issue 46320](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/46320#issuecomment-846403868) is counter-intuitive and confusing indeed.

Comment: Looks like [issue 61372](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/61372) is not happening right away.

Answer (score 78):

From what I understand, you want something like:

```
func IsZeroOfUnderlyingType(x interface{}) bool {
    return x == reflect.Zero(reflect.TypeOf(x)).Interface()
}
```

When talking about interfaces and `nil`, people always get confused with two very different and unrelated things:

1. A `nil` interface value, which is an interface value that doesn't have an *underlying value*. This is the zero value of an interface type.
2. A non-`nil` interface value (i.e. it has an *underlying value*), but its underlying value is the zero value of its underlying type. e.g. the underlying value is a `nil` map, `nil` pointer, or 0 number, etc.

It is my understanding that you are asking about the second thing.

---

**Update**: Due to the above code using `==`, it won't work for types that are not *comparable*. I believe that using `reflect.DeepEqual()` instead will make it work for all types:

```
func IsZeroOfUnderlyingType(x interface{}) bool {
    return reflect.DeepEqual(x, reflect.Zero(reflect.TypeOf(x)).Interface())
}
```

Comment: PS: should be probably modified to `x == nil || x == reflect.Zero(reflect.TypeOf(x)).Interface()` or it will panic on `nil`

Comment: @ErikAigner: well, it depends on what exactly you are looking for. If you want to be able to detect the `nil` interface itself too, then yes, you should add that. But in the question, you said that there's a int/string/bool/etc.. stored inside the interface

Comment: Fails with `map[string]string`. Is there anyway to make this supports maps short of casting and checking `len` ?

Answer (score 4):

The [zero value](http://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value)* of type `interface{}` is only `nil`, not `0` or `""` or `false`.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
        var v interface{}
        fmt.Println(v == nil, v == 0, v == "", v == false)
}
```

(Also http://play.golang.org/p/z1KbX1fOgB)

---

Output

```
true false false false
```

---

*: [Q]When memory is allocated to store a value, either through a declaration or a call of make or new, and no explicit initialization is provided, the memory is given a default initialization. Each element of such a value is set to the zero value for its type: false for booleans, 0 for integers, 0.0 for floats, "" for strings, and nil for pointers, functions, interfaces, slices, channels, and maps.[/Q]

Comment: so basically I can check via `reflect.ValueOf(i) == reflect.Zero(reflect.TypeOf(int(0)))` replacing `int` with every type I want to check?

Comment: Your question as stated in the OP IMHO doesn't require any use of reflection, IIUC(?). A zero value of `interface{}` compares equal to `nil`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize what you meant. I guess this illustrates my question better http://play.golang.org/p/qFmrij9RYQ

Comment: I'm confused. That _does not_ compare a zero value of `interface{}` but an `interface{}` typed argument carrying one of the passed values. All of those, except for untyped the `nil` are not zero values. What exactly do you mean by `empty/uninitialized`? It doesn't seem to be the same as the zero value, but what it is then?

Comment: No, that has other problems. http://play.golang.org/p/Rr7kjltONj. The only way I can think to do this is http://play.golang.org/p/nKsjDU1OzI. However, that doesn't work in the playground because of its use of unsafe.

Comment: I quite don't get what's so hard to understand about my question. I just wanted to know how to check if an `int`/`string`/`pointer`/etc.. stored in an `interface{}` is `0`/`""`/`pointer`/etc...

Comment: The confusion stems from that such value is not "empty/uninitialized" as that was asked in the question (before the recent edit). Even after that edit the new use of the word "uninitialized" is not making too much sense. There are only zero values and non zero values of every Go entity. You probably mean 'uninitialized' wrt semantics of some specific goal, but no one knows that. Precise questions, using the by-specs defined terms, get better answers ;-)

Comment: Sorry about that, but you can't assume people asking stupid questions (like me) have a complete grasp of Go's terminology :)

Answer (score 1):

@newacct's answer can't detect raw zero value, calling `reflect.Value.Interface()` on which will cause error. It can use `reflect.Value.IsValid()` to check that.

```
// IsValid reports whether v represents a value.
// It returns false if v is the zero Value.
// If IsValid returns false, all other methods except String panic.
// Most functions and methods never return an invalid value.
// If one does, its documentation states the conditions explicitly.
func (v Value) IsValid() bool
```

Update the methods:

```
func IsZero(v reflect.Value) bool {
    return !v.IsValid() || reflect.DeepEqual(v.Interface(), reflect.Zero(v.Type()).Interface())
}

func TestIsZero(t *testing.T) {
    var p *string
    v := reflect.ValueOf(p)

    assert.Equal(t, true, v.IsValid())
    assert.True(t, IsZero(v))

    assert.Equal(t, uintptr(0), v.Pointer())

    v = v.Elem()
    assert.Equal(t, false, v.IsValid())
    assert.True(t, IsZero(v))
}
```