# Exclude empty fields from struct iteration

Tags: go

I have a struct that will get its value from user input.
Now I want to extract only field names that have associated values. Fields with a `nil` value should not be returned. How can I do that?

Here’s my code:

```
package main


import "fmt"
import "reflect"

type Users struct {
    Name string
    Password string
}


func main(){
    u := Users{"Robert", ""}

    val := reflect.ValueOf(u)


    for i := 0; i < val.NumField(); i++ {

        fmt.Println(val.Type().Field(i).Name)

    }


}
```

Current Result:

```
Name
Password
```

Expected result:

```
Name
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write a function to check for empty:

```
func empty(v reflect.Value) bool {
    switch v.Kind() {
    case reflect.Int, reflect.Int8, reflect.Int16, reflect.Int32, reflect.Int64:
        return v.Int() == 0
    case reflect.Uint, reflect.Uint8, reflect.Uint16, reflect.Uint32, reflect.Uint64:
        return v.Uint() == 0
    case reflect.String:
        return v.String() == ""
    case reflect.Ptr, reflect.Slice, reflect.Map, reflect.Interface, reflect.Chan:
        return v.IsNil()
    case reflect.Bool:
        return !v.Bool()
    }
    return false
}
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/vcl_f7MsV-).

Comment: `default: return reflect.DeepEqual(v.Interface(), reflect.Zero(v.Type()).Interface())` would also (inefficiently) handle fields that are themselves structs.

Comment: Thanks. But, I simplify it lil bit below. :)

Comment: Please, use `isZero()` method from `reflect` package now. details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57613511

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. Case closed. :)

```
import "fmt"
import "reflect"

type Users struct {
    Name string
    Password string
}


func main(){
    u := Users{"robert", ""}

    val := reflect.ValueOf(u)

    var fFields []string

    for i := 0; i < val.NumField(); i++ {
    f := val.Field(i)

    if f.Interface() != "" {
        fFields = append(fFields, val.Type().Field(i).Name)
    }

    }

   fmt.Println(fFields)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/QVIJaNXGQB

Comment: Great--though I'd be inclined to accept 4of4's answer because the question's phrasing covers non-string fields too, and the more general answer could be useful for folks researching this problem later. (It also doesn't "cost" you anything to accept it, so to speak.)