# How to know if a variable of arbitrary type is Zero in Golang?

Tags: go, reflection, go-reflect

Because not all types are comparable, e.g. a slice. So we can't do this

```
var v ArbitraryType
v == reflect.Zero(reflect.TypeOf(v)).Interface()
```

Answer (score 10):

Go 1.13 introduced `Value.IsZero` method in `reflect` package. This is how you can check for zero value using it:

```
if reflect.ValueOf(v).IsZero() {
    // v is zero, do something
}
```

Apart from basic types, it also works for Chan, Func, Array, Interface, Map, Ptr, Slice, UnsafePointer, and Struct.

Answer (score 4):

#### Reflect

It depends of what behavior you want when `v` is an interface (for other types it's the same):

- `reflect.ValueOf(v).IsZero()` checks whether the value **boxed** in the interface is zero
- `reflect.ValueOf(&v).Elem().IsZero()` checks whether the interface variable is zero

Demonstration ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/-FiZkQNkB3X)):

```
var v interface{} = ""
fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(v).IsZero())           // true, the empty string "" is zero
fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(&v).Elem().IsZero())   // false, the interface itself is not zero
```

The difference is due to the argument of `ValueOf` being `interface{}`. If you pass an interface, it will unbox the dynamic value boxed in it. The Go docs of `ValueOf` remind that:

> ValueOf returns a new Value initialized to **the concrete value stored in the interface i**

By using `ValueOf(&v)` instead "the concrete value stored in the interface i" will be a pointer to `v`. Then you dereference with `Elem()` to get the original value and finally check `IsZero()`.

Most often than not, what you want is probably `reflect.ValueOf(&v).Elem().IsZero()`, though YMMV.

#### Go 1.18 and generics

With generics, you can check if a variable is zero value by using the `==` operator on a `var zero T` or `*new(T)`. The type parameter **must be comparable** (`comparable` constraint or type set of comparable types).

```
func IsZeroVar[T ~int64 | ~string](v T) bool {
    var zero T
    return v == zero
}

func IsZeroNew[T ~int64 | ~string](v T) bool {
    return v == *new(T)
}
```

If the type param is not comparable, you must fall back to reflection, as shown above.

Comment: What would be the benefit of using the generic version instead of reflect, given that it introduces the additional constraint on the type being comparable?

Comment: @RyanCollingham if you need to use this function for *any* type at all, the generic version doesn’t in fact offer benefits. It is an alternative vs. reflection only when the types you plan to compare are or can be restricted to comparable ones

Comment: answering my own question here but it seems that the generic version is significantly faster, by a couple orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 3):

As Peter Noyes points out, you just need to make sure you're not comparing a type which isn't comparable. Luckily, this is very straightforward with the `reflect` package:

```
func IsZero(v interface{}) (bool, error) {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(v)
    if !t.Comparable() {
        return false, fmt.Errorf("type is not comparable: %v", t)
    }
    return v == reflect.Zero(t).Interface(), nil
}
```

See an example use [here](https://play.golang.org/p/zDE0csOqZ_).

Answer (score 2):

Both of the following give me reasonable results (probably because they're the same?)

```
reflect.ValueOf(v) == reflect.Zero(reflect.TypeOf(v)))

reflect.DeepEqual(reflect.ValueOf(v), reflect.Zero(reflect.TypeOf(v)))
```

e.g. various integer 0 flavours and uninitialized `struct`s are "zero"

Sadly, empty strings and arrays are not. and `nil` gives an exception.
You could special case these if you wanted.

Comment: Hi Rhythmic, Thanks for your response! In fact, == and DeepEqual are different. DeepEqual works for both comparable and non comparable variable, according to go document [reflect.DeepEqual](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual)

Comment: I'm yet to understand comparable, I'll check it out, thanks.