# How do I use reflect.DeepEqual() to compare a pointer's value against the zero value of its type?

Tags: go, reflection

I need a generic function to check whether something is equal to its zero-value or not.

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901819/quick-way-to-detect-empty-values-via-reflection-in-go), I was able to find a function that worked with value types. I modified it to support pointers:

```
func isZeroOfUnderlyingType(x interface{}) bool {

    rawType := reflect.TypeOf(x)

    //source is a pointer, convert to its value
    if rawType.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        rawType = rawType.Elem()
    }

    return reflect.DeepEqual(x, reflect.Zero(rawType).Interface())
}
```

Unfotunately, this didn't work for me when doing something like this:

```
type myStruct struct{}

isZeroOfUnderlyingType(myStruct{}) //Returns true (works)

isZeroOfUnderlyingType(&myStruct{}) //Returns false (doesn't) work
```

This is because `&myStruct{}` is a pointer and there is no way to dereference an `interface{}` inside the function. How do I compare the value of that pointer against the zero-value of its type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reflect.Zero()` returns a `reflect.Value`. `reflect.New()` returns a pointer to a zero value.

I updated the function to check the case where `x` is a pointer to something:

```
func isZeroOfUnderlyingType(x interface{}) bool {

    rawType := reflect.TypeOf(x)

    if rawType.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        rawType = rawType.Elem()
        return reflect.DeepEqual(x, reflect.New(rawType).Interface())
    }

    return reflect.DeepEqual(x, reflect.Zero(rawType).Interface())
}
```