# How to find empty struct values in Go using reflection?

Tags: go, reflection

I have been looking and been struggling with this for a bit. I found this other Stack Overflow question which put me in the right direction but isn't working: [Quick way to detect empty values via reflection in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901819/quick-way-to-detect-empty-values-via-reflection-in-go).

My current code looks like this:

```
structIterator := reflect.ValueOf(user)
for i := 0; i < structIterator.NumField(); i++ {
    field := structIterator.Type().Field(i).Name
    val := structIterator.Field(i).Interface()

    // Check if the field is zero-valued, meaning it won't be updated
    if reflect.DeepEqual(val, reflect.Zero(structIterator.Field(i).Type()).Interface()) {
        fmt.Printf("%v is non-zero, adding to update\n", field)
        values = append(values, val)
    }
}
```

However I have `fmt.Printf` which prints out the `val` and the `reflect.Zero` I have, and even when they both are the same, it still goes into the `if` statement and every single field is read as non-zero even though that is clearly not the case. What am I doing wrong? I don't need to update the fields, just add them to the slice *values* if they aren't zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, you are adding `val` to the `values` slice if `val` **IS** the zero value, not if it isn't. So you should probably check `if !reflect.DeepEqual(...` instead of what you have. Other than that, your code seems to work fine:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type User struct {
    Name  string
    Age   int
    Email string
}

func main() {

    user, values := User{Name: "Bob", Age: 32}, []interface{}(nil)

    structIterator := reflect.ValueOf(user)
    for i := 0; i < structIterator.NumField(); i++ {
        field := structIterator.Type().Field(i).Name
        val := structIterator.Field(i).Interface()

        // Check if the field is zero-valued, meaning it won't be updated
        if !reflect.DeepEqual(val, reflect.Zero(structIterator.Field(i).Type()).Interface()) {
            fmt.Printf("%v is non-zero, adding to update\n", field)
            values = append(values, val)
        }
    }
}
```

outputs the following ([Go Playground Link](https://play.golang.org/p/uGWe1BZHV1H)):

```
Name is non-zero, adding to update
Age is non-zero, adding to update
```

So it is correctly seeing that the `Email` field is not initialized (or more correctly, contains the zero value for `string`).

Comment: Yep I'm dumb, all I needed was the exclamation point to reverse the check. Thanks!