# How to create methods for string type in Golang

Tags: go

I'm planning to create some method extension for the string type.

I need to write all my extension methods into a separate package.

here is my hierarchy.

```
root
|    main.go
|    validation
     |   validate.go
```

on the `main.go` I would like to have, `"abcd".Required()`

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "./validation"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println( "abcd".Required() )
}
```

**validate.go**

```
package validation

func (s string) Required() bool {

    if s != "" {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

When I run it, will get an error.

**error**

```
cannot define new methods on non-local type string
```

I found some answers in other questions on StackOverflow but they don't exactly talk about the string type & having the method in a different package file.

Comment: As the error says: you can't define methods on the `string` type. You may however create a new type (e.g. `type mystring string`), and add methods to the new type.

Comment: @icza yes, that's true. i've tired that but still doesn't work as i expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your validate.go create a new type `String`:

```
package validation

type String string

func (s String) Required() bool {

    return s != ""
}
```

And then work with `validation.String` objects in your main:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "./validation"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(validation.String("abcd").Required())
}
```

An executable example with it all in the same file here:

https://play.golang.org/p/z_LcTZ6Qvfn

Comment: `return s != ""`

Comment: @IainDuncan this works. tnx. but I wonder how can we have ```validation.String("abcd").Reqired()``` much simpler.

Comment: How can we actually accept any type not only string in this example?

Comment: @usr784638 if it is treating for the zero value of any field then you could do that via reflection like this question https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901819/quick-way-to-detect-empty-values-via-reflection-in-go&ved=2ahUKEwjZ94L1pY3gAhUytHEKHYPsDecQjjgwAHoECAcQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3pMO8hlP8Z5DP8YJIEYu48